# Limit counter in range

Tags: php, wordpress, counter

I'm trying to add a counter inside a WordPress loop that goes from 1 to 3. When it reaches 3 it starts again at 1.
This just increments the counter but doesn't stop at 3...

```
<?php
...
query_posts( $args );
$i=1;$i<=3;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $i++;
?>
<div ...>
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slideshow<?php echo $i; ?>.jpg" />
</div>
<?php
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one!

```
<?php
...
query_posts( $args );
$i=1;$i<=3;
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); $i++;
?>
<div ...>
    <img src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/images/slideshow<?php echo $i; ?>.jpg" />
</div>
<?php
if($i==3){ exit();}
endwhile;

// Reset Query
wp_reset_query();
?>
```

Comment: Mmmh.. actually that seems to work but it breaks my slider... Now all 3 divs are displayed and the display:none isn't applied to the non active ones.. http://pastebin.com/t6cMAkPt

Comment: Ops, sorry I noticed that even if I set posts_per_page to 20 the loop stops at 3..

Comment: Great!!..But you did't mention that ideal way, So that's why.

Answer (score 0):

It was easier than I thought :)

```
if($i==3){ $i=0; }
```